# Usage of "durchpowern"

Tags: word-usage

> Aber genau in solchen Situationen muss man einfach **durchpowern**!

In conversation, I just heard this said in a context where my friend, the speaker, was fighting the urge to doze off  after a long day at work.

Is it an anglicism or a slang word, as I can't seem to find it in several dictionaries? If so, how is this expression commonly paraphrased into something more *standard*?

Comment: sounds like a contamination of _durchkämpfen_ and _auspowern_

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a loan translation of English *power through* "to continue in a strong and determined way until the end of something, even when this is difficult" ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/power-through-sth)). [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/powern) actually has *powern* as a verb, so particle verbs based on it are to be expected.

As a replacement, I would suggest combining two figures of speech:

> Aber genau in solchen Situationen muß man einfach **die Zähne zusammenbeißen** und nochmal **Gas geben**!

<sub>Loong mentioned *auspowern* in a comment. I know this verb with the meaning "sich verausgaben", with *powern* pronounced in the English manner [paʊ̯ɐn]. However, [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auspowern_ausbeuten) has a verb *auspowern* with the meaning "ausbeuten", with *powern* pronouned [poːvɐn], which I have never heard.</sub>

Comment: Das deutsch ausgesprochene "auspowern" kommt von frz. pauvre, arm: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/power. -ower* ist selten, möglicherweise nur in Lehnwörtern, wie in "ausbaldowern" aus Rotwelsch.

Comment: it's quite certainly a loan translation as you describe. 'am Ende des Tages' is another one of those.

Comment: "auspowern" englisch ausgesprochen scheint ursprünglich eine Reanalyse der geschriebenen Form gewesen zu sein.